# grails 2.5+ Duplicate class definition error when implementing serializable on a controller

Tags: grails

Upgrading a legacy system of grails. One of the controllers implements Serializable. This is throwing the following error in newer versions of grails:

```
Invalid duplicate class definition of class com.regional.ScheduleController : 
The source contains at least two definitions of the class. 
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, 
the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. 
Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.
```

The solution mentioned would  break (previous) grails convention. Anyone know how to handle this in grails 2.5+?

**EDIT**

Serializable is not the issue. I tried removing it and got the same error.
I found this explanation from  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940202/getting-org-codehaus-groovy-control-multiplecompilationerrorsexception-using-gma):

```
IN groovy.. class B{} is a class structure and defines a class B. 
Scripts are classes too.
 Now you may create a B.groovy, with the content "class B{}; def b = new B()". 
There would be one class named B, and a script with the very same name.
This is a conflict.
```

However this does not explain why it runs fine below grails 2.5 and not above it. And I can't find a def conflict like the one mentioned above in that controller.

**ANSWER**:
One of the imports was what was actually failing- in a way that caused groovy to generate a class definition based on the current file name. When it hit the class definition, there was already an auto generated class name to collide with.

Comment: Why would a controller need to be serializable?

Comment: I believe it is implementing Serializable to work with a JasperReports functionality it uses. I tried removing serializable and the error remained the same....